# Can I use Lua's require to set environment of the calling file?

Tags: lua, lua-5.1, behavior-tree

Is there a way to call `require` in a Lua file, and have the module set the environment of the file that calls it? For example, if I have a DSL (domain specific language) that defines the functions `Root` and `Sequence` defined in a table, can I have something like `setfenv(1, dslEnv)` in the module that allows me to access those functions like global variables?

The goal I in mind is using this is a behavior tree DSL in a way that makes my definition file look like this (or as close it as possible):

```
require "behaviortrees"

return Root {
    Sequence {
        Leaf "leafname",
        Leaf "leafname"
    }
}
```

without having to specifically bring `Root`, `Sequence`, and `Leaf` into scope explicitly or having to qualify names like `behaviortrees.Sequence`.

In short, I'm trying to make the definition file as clean as possible, without any extraneous lines cluttering the tree definition.

Comment: One of the points of `require` is that it isolates the requested module from the caller. If you want, you can copy any number of members from the returned table. Also, the `debug`-module contains functions breaking many of the normal rules.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you use these functions generally, then it is better to manually local each one, so at least all compilers can optimize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Can I have something like `setfenv(1, dslEnv)` in the module that allows me to access those functions like global variables?

Sure you can. You just have to figure out the correct stack level to use instead of the `1` in your `setfenv` call. Usually you'd walk up the stack using a loop with `debug.getinfo` calls until you find the `require` function on the stack, and then you move some more until you find the next main chunk (just in case someone calls `require` in a function). This is the stack level you'd have to use with `setfenv`. But may I suggest a ...

## Different Approach

`require` in Lua is pluggable. You can add a function (called a searcher) to the `package.loaders` array, and `require` will call it when it tries to load a module. Let's suppose all your DSL files have a `.bt` suffix instead of the usual `.lua`. You'd then use a reimplementation of the normal Lua searcher with the differences that you'd look for `.bt` files instead of `.lua` files, and that you'd call `setfenv` on the function `return`ed by `loadfile`. Something like this:

```
local function Root( x ) return x end
local function Sequence( x ) return x end
local function Leaf( x ) return x end


local delim = package.config:match( "^(.-)\n" ):gsub( "%%", "%%%%" )

local function searchpath( name, path )
  local pname = name:gsub( "%.", delim ):gsub( "%%", "%%%%" )
  local msg = {}
  for subpath in path:gmatch( "[^;]+" ) do
    local fpath = subpath:gsub( "%?", pname ):gsub("%.lua$", ".bt") -- replace suffix
    local f = io.open( fpath, "r" )
    if f then
      f:close()
      return fpath
    end
    msg[ #msg+1 ] = "\n\tno file '"..fpath.."'"
  end
  return nil, table.concat( msg )
end


local function bt_searcher( modname )
  assert( type( modname ) == "string" )
  local filename, msg = searchpath( modname, package.path )
  if not filename then
    return msg
  end
  local env = { -- create custom environment
    Root = Root,
    Sequence = Sequence,
    Leaf = Leaf,
  }
  local mod, msg = loadfile( filename )
  if not mod then
    error( "error loading module '"..modname.."' from file '"..filename..
           "':\n\t"..msg, 0 )
  end
  setfenv( mod, env ) -- set custom environment
  return mod, filename
end


table.insert( package.loaders, bt_searcher )
```

If you put this in a module and `require` it once from your main program, you can then `require` your DSL files with the custom environment from `.bt` files somewhere where you would put your `.lua` files as well. And you don't even need the `require("behaviortrees")` in your DSL files. E.g.:

File `xxx.bt`:

```
return Root {
  Sequence {
    Leaf "leafname",
    Leaf "leafname"
  }
}
```

File `main.lua`:

```
#!/usr/bin/lua5.1
require( "behaviortrees" ) -- loads the Lua module above and adds to package.loaders
print( require( "xxx" ) ) -- loads xxx.bt (but an xxx Lua module would still take precedence)
```

Comment: So, user program (`xxx.bt`) written on DSL must be `require()`-ed instead of just executed as usual program (`dofile()`-ed)?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Yes, `dofile` won't work. But I rarely use it anyway. Either the DSL file belongs to my program, in which case I use `require`, or it is user-supplied, in which case I use `loadfile` + `pcall`. In the latter case it is trivial to insert a `setfenv`.

Comment: Why not use straightforward solution: redefine `dofile`?  Internally it would do the same: check the file extension, `loadfile` + `setfenv` + `pcall`, but this would look more natural than using `require` for such unexpected purpose (loading non-modules).

Comment: You are free to do that, I prefer not to redefine `dofile` -- especially if the semantics are different. `dofile` is `loadfile` + call, not `loadfile` + `pcall`. But of course `loadfile` + `setfenv` + `pcall` is a valid option.

Comment: I mean `dofile` should be redefined only for `.bt` files, it should do its usual work for all the other files.  `dofile` is used by most Lua people for EXECUTING a code, while `require` is used for caching the modules and prevent repetitive executions.  When you are using `require` for usual executing - that's quite misleading.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: `dofile` just doesn't fit because it uses a non-protected call, and people expect it to do so. Overloading `dofile` for `.bt`-files to do a `pcall` is misleading, IMHO. If your DSL file is part of your application (and not user-supplied), I find `require` quite fitting, and you usually want the caching and path searching. The ability to load a non-Lua-based DSL dialect via a traditional parser in the same way, and to mock your DSL using a plain Lua module comes as a bonus. And if it is user-supplied, `lodfile` + `pcall` is clearer than a non-standard `dofile` overload.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Lua 5.2, `_ENV` is a local that determinates the environment table. You can change the environment of any function, basically, the chunk.

```
_ENV = behaviortrees;
```

Another way is to automatically copy each field:

```
do
    _ENV = _ENV or _G;

    for k, v in next, behaviortrees do
        _ENV[k] = v;
    end
end
```

However it might be more efficient to manually local each field from `behaviortrees`.

Comment: About your comment in parentheses, a chunk is a function.

Comment: @lhf Thanks, I've clarified now.

Comment: @Hand1Cloud I didn't know you could change the environment of a do end chunk! That's pretty cool. Unfortunately though, I'm using Lua 5.1, which doesn't use the _ENV table. I didn't specify that explicitly in my post (there was a reference to setfenv, but that's pretty easy to miss), sorry about that. +1 still for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 1):

**Module "behaviortrees.lua"**

```
local behaviortrees = {
   -- insert your code for these functions
   Root     = function(...) ... end,
   Sequence = function(...) ... end,
   Leaf     = function(...) ... end,
}

-- Now set the environment of the caller.  Two ways are available:

-- If you want to make DSL environment isolated from Lua globals
-- (for example, "require" and "print" functions will not be available 
--  after executing require "behaviortrees")
setfenv(3, behaviortrees)
-- or 
-- If you want to preserve all globals for DSL
setfenv(3, setmetatable(behaviortrees, {__index = getfenv(3)}))
```

---

**Main Lua program:**

```
require "behaviortrees"

return Root {
   Sequence {
      Leaf "leafname",
      Leaf "leafname"
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach for mixing with globals +1